# How to force classifier on transitive dependencies?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, maven-3

I have dependencies:

- `A`
- `B` (that also depends on `A`).

Now, I want to use specifier on `A`, lets say: `A-foo`. However, `B` still depends on `A` and as a result, I get both `A-foo` and `A` included in the target artifact.

Is there a way to force classifier on certain dependency?

### Why?

The reason why I need this is the following.

My `A` is a Java library built on Java8 but packaged as [Multi-Release Jar](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238) which means it contains additional classes for when jar is run on Java9.

Unfortunately, some old tools and servers are not aware of MR Jars and this makes them not working.

For that reason I have `A-foo` version of my library, that is without any extra classes, so old server can run it.

However, if user is using library `B` that depends on my `A`, he will simply get the MRJar version of `A` and it will fail again. I want to be able to prevent this somehow.

Comment: About the "Why"-part: If B is able to run on the A-foo version of the library, why don't you just use this as a dependency for B always? This seems like the simple way out. If your application is really more complicated and you want to void loading both A and A-foo, you need to handle this through version numbers. If you have a version 1.0.0 and a version 1.0.0-MRJar, then Maven will load just one of them and it easy to replace one by the other.

Comment: Because 1) B is not in my control 2) B should use A if possible, as it gives more performance 3) B needs A if on Java9.

Comment: I would define A-foo as a different version of A (as discussed above). Then it is easy to override the version number with dependencyManagement (and therefore replace A by A-foo). Classifier is not the right approach. You can even try to use profiles and activate/deactivate them based on the Java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gradle this is possible with the following code:

```
compile ('org.jodd:jodd-core:4.1.4:jre9') {
    force = true
}
compile ('org.jodd:jodd-joy:4.1.4') {
    exclude group: 'org.jodd', module:'jodd-core'
}
```

This means:

- force *classifier* usage of a library;
- excluded transitive non-*classifier* dependencies of a library

Answer (score 1):

An artifact with a classifier is a different artifact, not just a different version of the same artifact. It cannot replace - neither technically nor logically - the original artifact, meaning: Even if you would find a way around it technically, it goes against Maven logic.

If you describe in more detail which problem you want to solve, one can probably find a "Maven way" to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I really don't know how to explain it simpler than this :( This is exactly what I have as an issue.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you want to do this replacement.

Comment: Ok, just did it.

Comment: Doesnt gradle actually has a way to specify transitive dependency?